# AVX vs. SSE: expect to see a larger speedup

Tags: performance, sse, simd, avx

I expected AVX to be about 1.5x faster than SSE. All 3 arrays (3 arrays * 16384 elements *4 bytes/element = 196608 bytes) should fit in L2 cache (256KB) on an Intel Core CPU (Broadwell).

Are there any special compiler directives or flags that I should be using?

**Compiler Version**

```
$  clang --version
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

**Compile line**

```
$  make avx
clang -O3 -fno-tree-vectorize -msse -msse2 -msse3 -msse4.1 -mavx -mavx2 avx.c ; ./a.out 123
n: 123
  AVX Time taken: 0 seconds 177 milliseconds
vector+vector:begin int: 1 5 127 0

  SSE Time taken: 0 seconds 195 milliseconds
vector+vector:begin int: 1 5 127 0
```

**avx.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <time.h>
#ifndef __cplusplus
#include <stdalign.h>   // C11 defines _Alignas().  This header defines alignas()
#endif
#define REPS 50000
#define AR 16384

// add int vectors via AVX
__attribute__((noinline)) 
void add_iv_avx(__m256i *restrict a, __m256i *restrict b, __m256i *restrict out, int N) {

    __m256i *x = __builtin_assume_aligned(a, 32);
    __m256i *y = __builtin_assume_aligned(b, 32);
    __m256i *z = __builtin_assume_aligned(out, 32);

    const int loops = N / 8; // 8 is number of int32 in __m256i
    for(int i=0; i < loops; i++) { 
        _mm256_store_si256(&z[i], _mm256_add_epi32(x[i], y[i]));
    }
}

// add int vectors via SSE; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict
__attribute__((noinline)) 
void add_iv_sse(__m128i *restrict a, __m128i *restrict b, __m128i *restrict out, int N) {

    __m128i *x = __builtin_assume_aligned(a, 16);
    __m128i *y = __builtin_assume_aligned(b, 16);
    __m128i *z = __builtin_assume_aligned(out, 16);

    const int loops = N / sizeof(int);
    for(int i=0; i < loops; i++) { 
        //out[i]= _mm_add_epi32(a[i], b[i]); // this also works
        _mm_storeu_si128(&z[i], _mm_add_epi32(x[i], y[i]));
    } 
}

// printing
void p128_as_int(__m128i in) {
    alignas(16) uint32_t v[4];
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)v, in);
    printf("int: %i %i %i %i\n", v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3]);
}

__attribute__((noinline)) 
void debug_print(int *h) {
    printf("vector+vector:begin ");
    p128_as_int(* (__m128i*) &h[0] );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = atoi (argv[1]);
    printf("n: %d\n", n);

    int *x,*y,*z;
    if (posix_memalign((void**)&x, 32, 16384*sizeof(int))) { free(x); return EXIT_FAILURE; }
    if (posix_memalign((void**)&y, 32, 16384*sizeof(int))) { free(y); return EXIT_FAILURE; }
    if (posix_memalign((void**)&z, 32, 16384*sizeof(int))) { free(z); return EXIT_FAILURE; }
    x[0]=0; x[1]=2; x[2]=4;
    y[0]=1; y[1]=3; y[2]=n;

    // touch each 4K page in x,y,z to avoid copy-on-write optimizations
    for (int i=512; i<AR; i+= 512) { x[i]=1; y[i]=1; z[i]=1; }

    // warmup
    for(int i=0; i<REPS; ++i) { add_iv_avx((__m256i*)x, (__m256i*)y, (__m256i*)z, AR); }
    // AVX
    clock_t start = clock();
    for(int i=0; i<REPS; ++i) { add_iv_avx((__m256i*)x, (__m256i*)y, (__m256i*)z, AR); }
    int msec = (clock()-start) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("  AVX Time taken: %d seconds %d milliseconds\n", msec/1000, msec%1000);
    debug_print(z);

    // warmup
    for(int i=0; i<REPS; ++i) { add_iv_sse((__m128i*)x, (__m128i*)y, (__m128i*)z, AR); }
    // SSE
    start = clock();
    for(int i=0; i<REPS; ++i) { add_iv_sse((__m128i*)x, (__m128i*)y, (__m128i*)z, AR); }
    msec = (clock()-start) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\n  SSE Time taken: %d seconds %d milliseconds\n", msec/1000, msec%1000);
    debug_print(z);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Rerun it several times in a loop, swap the order between SSE and AVX, etc. In the end, I get (on skylake) a ratio that is pretty close to the 1.5 you say you expect.

Comment: For such a tiny amount of compute per element (just an addition), I'd expect the execution time to be memory bound mostly.

Comment: You're on Broadwell, so you don't have Skylake's hardware P-state feature for fast ramp-up to max turbo.  36ms is very short for measuring wall-clock time (rather than core clock cycles).  There's also the AVX warm-up period of about 14 us where 256b instructions are maybe 4x slower: http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=415.  Agner says he didn't observe it on pre-Skylake, but others have.  Anyway, running SSE first would have some of its time at low clock speed, unless you controlled for that by warming up first.

Comment: You're also testing the cost of touching the output array for the first time.  (TLB misses and soft page faults).  That's probably pretty minor for 10k REPS on a small-ish array, though.  But this is stack memory, so touching new memory farther down the stack also requires the kernel to extend your stack mapping.  Depending on how gcc lays out the arrays on the stack, AVX touching `z[]` might extend the stack mapping to already include the `h[]` used by SSE.  Or maybe gcc is clever and reuses the dead x,y,z stack memory to save space, to the benefit of the 2nd loop.

Comment: Call the code once, without timing, to make sure memory is paged in, caches are warmed, clock speed has ramped up, etc, then call it in a loop with timing.

Comment: @AG1: Just check the compiler's asm output to make sure you got what you expected.  I'd probably reuse the same arrays for both tests.  I might put them in the BSS.  Either run more iterations or run a warm-up before the timed section as Paul R suggests.  If you make the iteration count nice and high, and only do AVX *or* SSE in one execution, you can profile the whole program with `perf stat` to get performance counters with the counts dominated by the real work you want to measure, not startup/cleanup.  (a couple seconds should be fine, esp. if you count core clock cycles, not seconds.)

Comment: Your change means that your timed portion is touching most of `x` and `y` for the first time, too.  Instead of zeroing the rest of `x` and `y` with a braced initializer, you're leaving them uninitialized.  (This means that other than the first page, they can both be copy-on-write mapped the same 4k physical page of zeros. so you get unexpectedly high amounts of L1D cache hits on the loads.)  But it also means you soft page fault more.  IDK why there's less diff than before.  Maybe you're getting 4k pages where you had 2M hugepages before?

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks for the advice. I wrote a ~8 elements for each 4K page for each array.  When I get access to a Linux box next week I'll try to use perf to see what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that that your data doesn't fit in the L1 cache.
The L1 bandwidth of Broadwell is much larger than the L2 bandwidth.
The L1 bandwidth is large enough to load two 32 byte vectors every cpu cycle. So, a better AVX vs. SSE speedup
might be expected if your data set is much smaller. However, note that
the combined L1 read/write bandwidth is less than 2*32(r)+32(w)=96 bytes per cycle.
In practice 75 bytes per cycle is possible, see [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-moderncode-for-parallel-architectures/topic/608964).

The second graph on [this](http://techreport.com/review/24879/intel-core-i7-4770k-and-4950hq-haswell-processors-reviewed/8) page shows that indeed the L2 bandwidth is much smaller:
At Test_block_size=128KB (=32KB per core) the bandwidth is 900GB/s.
At Test_block_size=1MB (=256KB per core) the bandwidth is only 300GB/s.
(Note that Haswell 4770k has more or less the same L1 and L2 cache architecture as Broadwell.)

Try to reduce `AR` to 2000 and to increase `NREP` to 1000000 and see what happens with the SSE vs. AVX speedup.

Comment: It occurs to me that gcc's loops are probably front-end bottlenecked as well.  Although that effect would be in favour of AVX2, because doing 2x the work per uop is a win.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, that might also play a role here. Reducing the array size `AR`to 2000 indeed resulted in an AVX vs. SSE speedup of 2, as expected.